# My Javascript library contains secrets. It is provided for websites to use. Is it possible to protect the secret from websites?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a javascript front-end library for websites to use. My library contains some secrets that websites should not be able to access to. (To be specific my library contains the secret key, and when sign() function called it will pop up another window to ask the user to sign) How can I prevent websites that use my library to steal the secret?

Comment: In short: not possible. Anything you allow to load to a browser is public and can't be hidden.

Comment: Bounce the request off of your own server instead of putting the secret in your library, if at all possible (else you can consider it compromised by any sufficiently determined malicious actor)

Comment: It is possible that a [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) solution may work for you.

Comment: Bouncing to my server is not possible since only the secret owner (user) is the only person that should be able to know the secret. I use shamir's scheme to shares secret among servers.

Comment: User sends the secret to the server, e.g. the passphrase to unlock the private key, server decrypts the message and sends the decrypted stream back. The private key never leaves the server.

Comment: @Adder Private Key is not on the server. And the server can not know the secret, Even encrypted one. BTW, For your solution After the secret sent back to client. How can I protect it from website anyway?

Comment: Hmm, then encrypt the key in the js library and decrypt it with a key provided by the user?

Comment: @Adder Yeah, decrypted by user but can website still access to it?

Comment: Well, yes the javascript has access to it after the user provided the key. But at least no one can gain access before the user provided the key. You would have different keys for different users, maybe set by an installation script or a database.

Answer (score 0):

All frontend Javascript code will be exposed to the public. It is not the best place to hide secrets because anyone can see it.

Because you said that you are developing a library, you can make the secret key as a part of the parameters that should be provided by the user of that library, something like this:

```js
// someone using your library
yourLibrary({
  secretKey: 'someSecretKey'
})
```

If this can't be an option for you, I think you have to store your secret key on a server elsewhere.